# Update Hyperledger ACL from transactions

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have `User` and `Buyer` participants on the network. Generally, the buyers cannot `READ` the user's data but I want to make `GrantAccess` and `RevokeAccess` transactions so the `User`s to have the option to grant and revoke the `READ` access from `Buyer`s

I haven't been able to find anything on how to do this, would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would run a 'tx_GrantAccess' transaction that firstly, updates a particular BUYER's record (eg. id *buyer123* - a participant modeled with a field called `access`, which is set to `true` by this transaction).

I can use a condition match (as a boolean) on the target BUYER records (resources) and if the BUYER, say *buyer123* (ie that's accessing the business network) has `access=true` then he can READ the USER records.

Transaction rule (needed by `User` to access the transaction classes)

```
rule rule_1 {
description: "grant access to User, for the 2 x Transactions themselves"
participant: "org.acme.example.User"
operation: CREATE
resource: "org.acme.example.tx_*"
action: ALLOW
}
```

User Access rule:

```
rule rule_2 {
description: "if granted access, allow READ of User by buyer"
participant(m): "org.acme.example.Buyer"
operation: READ
resource(v): "org.acme.example.User"
condition: (m.access)
action: ALLOW
}
```

where `Buyer` has a field (eg.

```
participant Buyer identified by id {
o String id
o Boolean access default=false
}
```

and your transaction `tx_GrantAccess` has a function that will set `access` to true on a particular Buyer's record and `tx_RevokeAccess` will set it to false etc.